# IP Address Information

Tags: ip, ip-address

When I connect from abroad to my host (home) computer and use it to access a casino in Europe, is there anyway my ISP in the country that i'm in at the time can tell that I am connected to the casino in Europe? It is my understanding that all they will see is that I am connected to my host computer and in no way can they see that I am connected to a casino connection in Europe. Is this correct?

Also can the casino see that I am accessing their casino through my host computer, via the abroad IP address? It is my understanding that all they can see is the IP address from my Canada computer and not the abroad IP. In other words, the Europe casino will in no way be able to tell that I am accessing through Team Viewer from another part of the world. Am I correct?

Thank you very much in advance for your help in clarifing this.

Comment: It all depends how you are connecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Team Viewer. The answer is Yes.
Your ISP only knows you're connecting to your host.
And the casino can only see your host's IP.

Do not use proxy, it may expose your real IP.
Do not use VPN, if it's disconnected, the casino client will reconnect directly to casino.